# iPad: Allocations show 3 MB memory while dirty memory continuously increases ans reaches greater than 100 MB

Tags: ipad, memory-management

I am working on an iPad app that includes lots of images, animations and videos. My app crashes after running 12 to 13 minutes. Allocations show me only 3 MB memory usage while in VM Tracker dirty memory continuously increases till it reaches 130 MB and then app crashes. But VM Tracker does not give me any insight about what is actually happening in the code and which piece of code is responsible for increasing dirty memory. I am badly stuck with it. Have tried every possible thing. I am not using [UIImage imageNamed:], have avoided autoreleased objects as long as I can,  have used autorelease pools where some convenience constructor is used. I am using FTUtils for animations in most places while in some places I am using [UIView beginAnimation:] but I am unable to reach any conclusion. Any help will be highly appreciated because I am badly stuck.

Comment: look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255080/fake-call-to-applicationdidreceivememorywarning-being-triggered-even-if-i-have-a

Comment: @samfisher But there is no answer given. My app does not only gets memory warnings.In fact it crashes after running for 12 to 13 minutes.